# The method schedule()/ cancel() is undefined for a type Timer

Tags: java

I tried to use `Timer` class, when I use `schedule()` and `cancel()` methods, 2 errors appear that methods are undefined for a type `Timer`. What can be the reason of it?

```
import java.util.*;
public class Timer{
    public static Timer timer = new Timer();  
    public static void main(String[] args){
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {  
        
            @Override  
            public void run(){  
                System.out.println("Task is on");  
                timer.cancel();
            };  
        };
        long delay = 1000;
        timer.schedule(task,delay);

}
```

Comment: Your own `Timer` class is shadowing `java.util.Timer`. Change the name of your class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are trying to use the util.Timer here with its predefined methods. However, you also name your own class Timer. The problem here is that you have the same name for two different things.

The compiler will first recognize your own classes before it searches through the util package. Therefore, the timer that you made is an object of your selfmade type Timer. This means that it also searches for methods in your class, where obviously no methods are defined.

A good practice to prevent these types of errors, is to use classes only to make objects. Personally, I always make a Main class that holds the public static void main, which is currently in your Timer class.  There, you would also add the line `public static Timer timer = new Timer();` .
Thus, I only make classes with other names than 'Main' for objects and they always have a constructor, even if I only use the default version.